# Is the site really cleaning up 1 rep users with no activity?

Tags: support

I thought I read somewhere that 1 rep users with no activity after period of time get deleted.

I wanted to check how many users are 1 rep, and I checked that a lot are without question\answer.
The page where users with 1 rep starts is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=35189&tab=reputation&filter=all), there's 92133 pages, minus 35189 (About 66% of the community having 1 rep), multiply by 36 users per page, about 2 million users having 1 rep.

Is there an explanation for so many 1 rep users?

Comment: There's 2,151,067 users with 1 rep according to this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/239572/test). And according to this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/239579/test), the average creation date of users with 1 rep is June 19th, 2013.

Comment: Probably because there was some activity on the accounts, as they gained more than 1 rep temporarily, and fell back because of downvoting. I'm guessing any activity on the account, prevents removal, though many users don't get (or don't care) how to improve for getting rep here.

Comment: I honestly think users should only be given an account if they answer or ask a question.  Why else would you need an account?

Comment: @IanWise: Voting, reviewing, commenting, favouriting, pretty much any other site activity.

Comment: oh, haha, I guess that's true, duh. =P

Comment: Fun fact, if each of these two million accounts somehow were able to upvote any post of Jon Skeets once, then they would effectively increase his reputation by 20 times.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Old user accounts are only deleted after 6 months of inactivity, and only if they have no visible posts. That will leave a lot of 1-rep accounts around.

For more detailed rules on that clean-up script, see [Shog9's answer to *Delete old, unloved, users*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146452/1288) .

Comment: "Is there an explanation for so many 1 rep users?" I guess it's just that it's really hard to be auto-removed by the automatic deletion process. So if a user posts any question or answer, the odds of them being removed have been lessened dramatically.

Comment: @cVplZ Right. Or if they just visit the site more often than once every 6 months, which many developers are going to do just by clicking on promising looking links on Google.

Comment: Also, the newest user Id I found is 4,191,660. In SEDE the count of users that haven't been removed is 3,602,033. Meaning there have been about 589,000 users removed.

Comment: Besides, a "user" is not only a "contributing" user, but also a "consuming" user, just looking for answers. Point of a Question/answer site is, it has answers. Ideally, as time goes, more and more people should stay at 1 rep, as it means they never needed to ask a question because it already has been answered.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Wouldn’t they get logged out inbetween? I get logged out more often than not (like, about every week), even I check most the SO sites I’m active on for content on a daily basis.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I'm not sure what the time out is. There are a handful of sites that I visit infrequently, and it seems like they keep me logged in for at least a month. My perception might be off though, since I use a lot of different SE sites.

Comment: "more people should stay at 1 rep" That's the part that's increasingly bugging me for quite some time.. It's getting more and more impossible to get a ticket to enter the church of sophia, so we really want a place 'dominated' (that's an unlucky word-choice) by the group that was most active during the first years of SO?

Comment: @GitaarLAB That's preferable to a place where the same questions keep getting asked and answered repeatedly. That doesn't mean *no one* can gain reputation. It just means you have to ask/answer new questions about new and/or changing technologies. It doesn't matter if it's the old members doing that, or if new people take their place.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: to that (your comment above), I *do* say (the equivalent of) amen! It was Kheldar's comment that I found a little to 'black & white'; as is/was more often discussed on meta: if it were that 'extreme', we might as well close up shop.

Comment: my 1 rep usecase is to (mis)use some accounts just to gather favourites, especially on SO

Comment: More people staying at 1 rep is nonsense.  New technologies emerge and join with existing technologies.  There are always opportunities to earn rep if you exercise your talent and persist.

Comment: I think if downvotes don't change the rep (i.e. 1 rep), that shouldn't count as activity. So inactive users would be cleaned after some time.