# Why aren't user accounts that only post spam auto deleted?

Tags: discussion, spam, accounts

Reviewing my [flagging history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/381149) I saw that many user accounts that have posted only one message (a spam) are still alive. What's the point? Increase the SO user stats? Shouldn't they have been auto deleted from the system?

Comment: the system seems to only remove account named userxxxxx ....

Comment: the understanding I got from the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295940/) was that account deletion is a manual process performed by moderators -- not an automatic one.

Comment: I think that an account who have post nothing more than a spam since says 90 days should be auto removed

Comment: Creating a new account is ridiculously easy, by spammers and blocked users alike.  Which do you like better, a known spammer account or one where you have to figure it out all over again?

Comment: The User account clean-up script doesn't run regularly and is known for having a backlog. See [this answer of mine for how that impact certain stats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-stack-overflow/296970#296970)

Comment: @HansPassant figure out who have post nothing more than a spam since says 90 days should not be so hard to implement IMO  :)

Comment: SO doesn't need to increase user stats; these accounts don't count as 'active' anyway. Yes, they should be autodeleted, eventually.

Comment: _"Shouldn't they have been auto deleted from the system?"_ Assuming they aren't (eventually)...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275534/is-the-site-really-cleaning-up-1-rep-users-with-no-activity

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam

Comment: @BoltClock this post have some really interresting suggestions about fighting spam and spamers

Comment: inactive spam account seems no effect on me, if remove them has technical issue I prefer not touching them, to prevent extra workload of moderator

Comment: When I ask the same kind of question it's 11 downvotes where as yours 20 upvotes. Good bye earth. Going to planet pluto :P  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306457/cant-we-delete-directly-delete-vote-to-delete-before-closing-a-question

Comment: @amuse keeping useless data is power and data consuming ...

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ your question was about deleting questions more hastily, and was rather confusingly phrased. It also had no real mechanical limitation, implying that *all* questions would potentially be subject to this at the whim of delvoters. They are two quite different questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A while ago, I actually [argued against something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165334/135615), but the reasons I gave there no longer apply. I had wanted these accounts to stick around long enough for us to use them to uncover other spammers at their IP address.

We now have other ways of doing this that don't require these accounts to hang around. Spammers are also less likely to come from the same location with relatively recent modifications to the intelligent spam-blocking system. There isn't as much of a need to keep them around for moderators to look at.

When moderators encounter accounts that only have one or two pure spam posts to their name, we almost always destroy them after we remove the spam posts. The ones that aren't deleted are typically the accounts that get posts destroyed by 6 community spam flags before we even notice them. That tends to happen when we're lightest on active moderators (night in the U.S.), so I'll tend to search back for these in the morning.

Keeping the accounts around generally doesn't do much, as they tend to be hard-blocked from posting after their initial post is destroyed as spam, but I've occasionally seen spammers revisit old accounts to use them to work around First Posts review. Most spammers tend to move on to new throwaway accounts at different locations once each has been spam-flagged.

As CRABOLO points out, many accounts like this are [automatically deleted after six months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275534/is-the-site-really-cleaning-up-1-rep-users-with-no-activity).

Looking at things now, I think it makes sense to automatically delete an account immediately if the only post or posts they have made are all destroyed by either 6 community spam flags or 1 hard moderator spam flag. That would save us a little time, and maybe a little follow-on spam. This automatic deletion would not apply to an account that had any posts that were not destroyed in this manner, so as to avoid possibly removing any accounts that had any value or to avoid malicious coordination of spam flags.

Comment: I just facepalmed so hard I knocked myself out. Who do I sue?

Comment: @Will I think you sue yourself for damages, then collect from yourself in an out-of-court settlement. I'd recommend using the money to go get ice cream to make you feel better, and maybe a band-aid if there's any bruising or splitting.

Comment: Wow, gr8 topic you are wrting about (www.greatrussianwives.com). This is superbly best on market right now, and you (www.facepalm-pills-82.net) defiantely know the words to describe (www.shoesplusmarket99.com).